# Page.Resources "the member resources is not recognized or is not accessible"

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, namespaces

Ok, I am getting an error while adding `<Page.Resources>` to my application. I've added a reference to my namespace and I get these errors:

> 1.) The member "Resources" is not recognized or is not accessible.
>
> 2.) The attachable property "Resources" was not found in type 'Page'.
>
> 3.) The attached property 'Page.Resources' is not defined on 'Window' or one of its base classes.

Here's the code in question:

[image]

I'm sure its simple but, what am I missing here?

Comment: As Mikko said: Page.Resources -> Window.Resources

Comment: I get a new error `The name "AgeToVisibilityConverter" does not exist in the namespace clr-namespace:databinding2`... AgeToVisibilityConverter is a class written in the namespace of databinding2 though

Comment: Check and doublecheck, clean and rebuild.

Comment: you got it... clean worked. Thanks mikko. I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: @MikkoViitala
I have Window.Resources and I get the error he is getting

Comment: Hi John, you should ask a new question